# linq count group only if all items in group are 'true'

Tags: c#, linq

Given the sample data below, I need a linq query that returns the number of items that are in stock at all 3 warehouses. In the example below, it should return `2`, because only skus `ABC-123` and `JKL-789` are ins stock at all 3 warehouses. But my query is returning 3?

```
WarehouseId     Sku         InStock
===================================
1               ABC-123     true
2               ABC-123     true
3               ABC-123     true

1               XYZ-789     true
2               XYZ-789     false
3               XYZ-789     true

1               JKL-456     true
2               JKL-456     true
3               JKL-456     true




int inStock = query.Where(x => x.InStock).GroupBy(x => x.Sku).Count();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your query returns 3 because your `Count()` is unrestricted, meaning that it counts all groups, not only the ones with all items present in stock.

Add a condition with a call to `All(item => item.InStock)` to count only the items that you need:

```
var inStock = query
    .GroupBy(x => x.Sku)
    .Count(g => g.All(item => item.InStock));
```

Note that `Where` is now gone, so that all items are included in groups.

Comment: You need to remove the where, otherwise you filter all items to be true and then check if they are true ;)

Comment: His query returns 3 because he takes only true in where

Answer (score 1):

```
int inStock = query
                .Where(x => x.InStock)
                .GroupBy(x => x.Sku)
                .Where(g=>g.Count() == 3)
                .Count();
```

Althought dasblinkenlight solution is better, as it covers adding new warehouses.